# IE6 HTTP \ HTTPS mixed content error

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I am getting the error that says some content is being delivered non secure over my secure page and i get the yes|no|more info dialog box.

Is there a way in IE6 to find out which element on my page is causing this error?

I have the developer tools, but that doesnt seem to tell me anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Clear your cookies and cache, and then run that as you load the page you will see all the resources load. There it is easy to see what's loading insecurely.

Comment: Also, if you have the dev tools, check out the Network tab-- when you set it to start capturing and reload the page it shows all of your resources loading too. Fiddler is just way more full-featured, so you should definitely get it.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be caused when accessing HTTP URIs from an HTTPS page.

Search for "http://" (or "https://", depending on which should be correct) in the HTML source?

Happy coding.